# Problems PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have two tables, user log that is where the people make a register with their email and password, and another table with the name user where the people make complete their own profile.

How can I make with an SQL query to insert the data that is inserted in the form?

Taking into account that table user makes reference with table user log with the id...

I mean

```
User log 
Id
Email
Password

User
Id
User_id fk id reference userlog(id)
Name
Surname
```

This is the code which I made the log in

```
<?php  
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

$errores = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $email = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = hash('sha512', $password);

    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE, 'USER', 'PASS');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();;
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM userlog WHERE email = :email AND password = :password'
    );
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':email' => $email,
        ':password' => $password
    ));

    $resultado = $statement->fetch();
    if ($resultado !== false) {
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado;
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        $errores .= '<li>Datos Incorrectos</li>';
    }
}
```

I make a var_dump() to see what the array in $resultado bring, and it bring me the data of the table, but, when I want to use the data to fill an input it fails

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Why have two tables? The data seems like it will always be a 1 to 1 relationship.

Comment: @Akin actualli I make a very few google search but it doesn't respond my question... I have the idea, but when i whant to implement, it crashes :'(  when i make a session I obviously declare de global variable of php $_SESSION['USER']; my intension is that with the fetch array print on a input type hidden the id value of the user that get logged and put that id in the user table, my idea is make it whith a inner join but it doesn't works!! The array crashes and i can't take the values

Comment: please submit your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: @chris85 I make it like that, I put all the information in just one table, but i come back to the same, when I whant to intoduce new data (I undestand that makes whith an UPDATE) in te $_SESSION['user']; i can't bring the data than have the array

Comment: I don't know what you mean with that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data will be coming from POST method, please always use precautions to avoid SQL injection..

I will be using a very elementary example. You can enhance this one for your own use.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "yourUser";
$password = "yourPass";
$dbname = "youtDB";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 
$sql = "INSERT INTO Userlog (email, password)
VALUES ('some_email@example.com', 'some_safe_password')"; 

$conn->exec($sql);
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
$userSql = "INSERT INTO Userlog (userId, name, lastName) VALUES ($last_id, 'some_name', 'some_lastName')";
$conn->exec($userSql);


}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: actualy i use PDO.

Comment: $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO prueba (id, nombre, apaterno, amaterno, profesion, ciudad, perfilprofe, perfilperso, tel, cel) VALUES (null, :nombre, :apaterno, :amaterno, :profesion, :ciudad, :perfilprofe, :perfilperso, :tel, :cel )');

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your data by using post method.
try this code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Userlog, Id, Email, Password)
        VALUES ('".$_POST["Userlog"]."','".$_POST["Id"]."','".$_POST["Email"].",'".$_POST["Password"]."')";
```